# UIScrollView scrollViewDidEndDecelerating not triggering

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UIScrollView`, created programmatically, inside of a `UIView`. What do I need to do to ensure that I can use the delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`?

Here's what I have set up, please assume that within the `UIScrollView`, that there are three `UIImageViews`. When the page first loads, I am looking at the center `UIImageView` and I can scroll once backwards or once forwards. The reason why I need this delegate method is because I intend to use it to calculate which `UIImageView` I am currently looking at.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

**ViewController.m**

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview: scrollView];

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDecelerating");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by looking at the center?

Comment: Hi Malloc, when I say "center" I mean the 2nd UIImageView. So in total if you can imagine UIImageViews [1] [2] [3], the page loads on [2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
 scrollView.delegate = self
```

after the scroll view initialization.

Answer (score 0):

In your delegate method, you can test each uiimageview center to see Which one match the uiview center, That's the uiimageview you are looking at.